# Using Emacs as Terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome-terminal, emacs

I want to know whether there is any way I can use Emacs as Terminal in Ubuntu. Means, I want to do the basic works with Emacs that I usually do with Terminal in Ubuntu, like 'sudo apt-get update'. I'll write this command and it'll update my Ubuntu system. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options, the perform the same basic function but there are some subtle differences. First you have M-term. This is a full fledged shell inside of an Emacs frame and responds the same as a terminal window and runs in it's own buffer. The issues I have with this is that you cannot switch buffers while the terminal is active, you must `exit` before changing buffers or performing any other common emacs tasks.

Your other option is M-eshell. This is a seemingly mor lightweight option that runs on top of your current buffer and allows you to switch buffers and execute Emacs commands from the mini-buffer while using eshell.

You might want to read over [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-ru/CategoryEshell) emacswiki page, has lots of good info on the topic.

Comment: So it works. Thanks. Now is there any easy way to learn to use Emacs as Terminal? I mean the wiki seams to be scary as I don't have that much knowledge on Shell. So any easy way of doing this might help me a lot. Any link?

Answer (score 1):

I did it. I used 'M-x Shell' in Emacs. That's it.